# Restoring a backup using SQLCommand in VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, sqlclient

I've got a VB.NET console application I'm creating that will make it easier for people to work with some test databases, and part of this is having a function that restores the database. I thought it was fairly straightforward, and here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Restore()
    con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=" & utilnamespace.sqlSvr & ";Database=Master;integrated security=SSPI;")
    cmd = New SqlCommand("ALTER DATABASE [db] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE RESTORE DATABASE db FROM DISK = 'G:\db.bak' WITH REPLACE, STATS = 10", con)
    cmd.Connection.Open()
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText)
    cmd.Connection.Close()

End Sub
```

The SQL works fine if I run it in SSMS, however it will time out if I try to run it from the app. The problem is that I've read over [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and I'm still unsure of what to do.

Should I use `BeginExecuteNonQuery` and then have it listen for the statement complete message somehow?

Comment: Search Google for SMO. It will do the work.

Comment: I was first trying to use a simple `RESTORE DATABASE` CommandText in my SqlCommand, but was encountering a `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: RESTORE cannot process database 'DbName' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation.` error message. Using your `ALTER DATABASE ...` CommandText bypassed this issue entirely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if I believe that showing a waiting form and waiting for some kind of confirmation would be better for the end user... have you tried changing the timeout in the connection string to solve it in a quick way?

eg (seconds):

```
string connStr = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=db;
       Integrated Security=SSPI;Connection Timeout=30";
```

Also check these links:

1. [SQL Server Management Objects (SMO)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26390/SQL-Server-2005-Database-Backup-and-Restore-using)
2. [SQL Server 2008 - Backup and Restore Databases using SMO](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123441/SQL-Server-2008-Backup-and-Restore-Databases-using)

Comment: I've thought about doing that, but it's not really solving the problem, just masking it. I'd rather just figure out how to have this run until completion and then move on, and I'm trying to figure out what the best way to do that will be. I agree, showing the waiting dialog is best. Maybe I could do that with BeginExecuteNonQuery(AsyncCallBack, Object)?

Comment: Or maybe I could just do a "Waiting..." message and wait for average time it takes for the backup to complete + 5 minutes.

Comment: @SeanLong If you take a look at the SMO link, there should be a progressStatus and Complete event that you can use

Comment: Yeah, just saw that. That's what I was missing! Good catch.

Comment: @SeanLong check also this, it may be useful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/123441/SQL-Server-2008-Backup-and-Restore-Databases-using

Answer (score 0):

If the database is too big you can increase the timeout of the Command, not the connection string

```
cmd.Connection.Open()
cmd.CommandTimeout = 100
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText)
cmd.Connection.Close()
```